# When reading an attribute from an instance in the database do I read the whole instance or just the attribute?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

If I wish to read an attribute of an instance (the instance is an NDB model) and I call, lets say, Instance.Attribute, does the code read the whole instance (everything about the instance I mean) from Cloud Datastore then filter the requested attribute or can it read the requested attribute directly?

In other words, if the instance has 8 attributes, does it count as 1 read or 8 read ops?

Thank you very much for your help. Any reference for your answers will be much appreciated as well!

Answer (score 1):

It reads the whole entity instance, and then you can seek your own attributes. Unless you use a projection query, but that is intended for querying multiple entity instances and not just one.

You can read google's [Bigtable whitepaper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf) if you're interested in knowing how it works.